# PDF.JS download same pdf multiple times

Tags: pdf.js

I am having the following problem. When I open the first document in pdf.js viewer and click the download button, that document is downloaded. But when I open a second document, and click download, that document is downloaded two times. And if I open a third document, click download, the document is downloaded three times. And so on. Do you have any ideia how I can resolve this issue?